# elastic stack difference between mysqlbeat and logstash jdbc input

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Is there any difference or recommandation using the first or the second one ?
Both bring mysql data to elastic

Thanks in advance :

https://github.com/adibendahan/mysqlbeat

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

Answer (score 1):

- **Push vs Pull**: Logstash's jdbc input *pulls* data from remote SQL servers on a cron, while the beat will *push* the results of the query to Elasticsearch.
- **Location**: Another thing to consider is that this beat will be running on every SQL server, vs having one Logstash with multiple jdbc input plugin blocks. There are pros and cons to this depending on your scale. If you have thousands of databases, it isn't scalable to have Logstash querying each one, particularly if the list of databases and queries are constantly changing. It would be much easier to manage one beat per SQL server. If you have a simple setup with just a few databases, it would probably be faster to use the Logstash input plugin, because then you wouldn't have another service to maintain (the beat).

Comment: Thanks it's more clear. But i gess it's possible to use logstash between elastic and mysqlbeat ?

Comment: Yep! You could also do mysqlbeat -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch and use Logstash for its filtering capabilities.